# How can I evaluate the below mentioned series without using a computation software?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, products

I have been trying to evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{2^{2^5}-1}\frac{2}{\prod_{n=1}^5\bigl((m+2)^{\frac{2}{n}}+(m)^{\frac{2}{n}}\bigr)}$ for quite a long time. I tried various approaches but failed. 
I'll be grateful if someone can help me out.

Comment: Could you let us know where this problem came from? Why do you expect that that monstrosity has a closed form at all?

Comment: This actually looks like a case where I would be very glad to have a computer algebra system do the work for me.

Comment: I thought it'll have a nice closed form. However, I'm not sure. Sorry for the inconvenience. Can you check if this has a closed form (if there's a way)?